# Excel VBA Passing a range of cells in column A to next columns with different range size

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of words in column A, so every word is in one cell.
I need to count entropy of specified range, so I need in column B range A1:A10, in column C range A1:A20, in column D range A1:A30 ...
The number of columns and cells in column A is always different because it takes different text every time.
I would need help with the VBA code for that.
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try on your own? What do you intend to do with respective ranges? I can show you, but how to use them, it is your job to explain...

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub FillUp()
    Dim items As Long, times As Long
    
    items = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    times = items / 10
    
    For i = 1 To times
        j = i * 10
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(j, 1)).Copy Range(Cells(1, i + 1), Cells(j, i + 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

This assumes that the number of items in column **A** is an even multiple of *10*

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of Gary's Student's answer and with a slight change in code, this would work also for number of items that is not a multiple of 10.

"test2" is the codename for the sheet I used.

> ```
> Sub FillUp()
>
>     Dim items As Long, times As Long
>
>     items = test2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
>     times = items / 10
>
>     Dim i As Long
>
>     For i = 1 To times
>
>         test2.Range("A1").Resize(10 * i, 1).Copy test2.Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
>     
>     Next i
>
>     If items Mod 10 <> 0 And items > 10 Then
>     
>         test2.Range("A1").Resize(items, 1).Copy test2.Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
>     
>     End If
>
> End Sub
> ```